# Restart all the tasks in array when completed

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I have an array of subTasks, which execute a method, Once the job is completed I get a notification and its over. Now I want them to restart the same job again, without any hassle. How is this possible?

This is how I am creating the task array and working with task completion:

```
public void Start()
        {

            this.totalRangePerThread = ((this.endRange - this.startRange) / this.subTasks.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < this.subTasks.Length; ++i)
            {
                var copy = startRange;
                this.subTasks[i] = new Task(() => searchItem(copy, this.totalRangePerThread), this.token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                this.startRange = this.startRange + this.totalRangePerThread;
            }

            //start tasks
            for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < this.subTasks.Length; ++taskIndex)
            {
                    this.subTasks[taskIndex].Start();     
            }
            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(this.subTasks, completedTasks =>
            {
                //write it onto the the activitylog
                if (Form1.Instance != null)
                {
                    Form1.Instance.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        Form1.Instance.AddItemtoActivityLog("Search Completed!");
                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

Should I make another call to the `Start()` method or there is a mechanism that just magically restarts the subtasks?

Comment: A simple call Start() inside ContinueWhenAll won't hurt much, :)

Comment: @David that was my first shot at it. But it didnt work out as expected.

Comment: try Task.WaitAll(), and then call start();

Comment: Where should `wait` command be placed?

Comment: I put it into an answer, as there is some code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the code for preparing and executing subtasks to a separate method. Then call it twice in your `Start()` method:

```
private void ExecuteSubTasks()
{
    var tasks = new Task[]
        {
            new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("SubTask1 executed.")),
            new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("SubTask2 executed.")),
            new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("SubTask3 executed.")),
        };

    foreach (var task in tasks)
        task.Start();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}

private void Start()
{
    var mainTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteSubTasks())
        .ContinueWith((prev) =>
        {
            ExecuteSubTasks();
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { MessageBox.Show("Completed."); });
        });
}
```

Comment: Much compact and feasible. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Start()
{
    var yourTasks = new Task[] {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => task1(),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => task2(),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => ...
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => taskN() };
    Task.WaitAll(yourTasks ); // wait for all N tasks to complete
    Start();
}
```

Comment: The `waitall` command halts the UI..I do want that, is there a work around this part?

Comment: The waitall command halts the UI? Are you calling on UI's thread? if so it is not hard to call Start() from new thread, but this is irrelevant with your original post!!!